# Is it possible to use a single EditResponseURL to edit the same response pushed to 2 different spreadsheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-forms

There is a form "A" that is linked to spreadsheet "B". No issues there.

I have set up a script that pushes responses to spreadsheet "B" and a different spreadsheet "C".

However, the issues start to occur when a respondent wishes to edit their response by using the edit URL emailed to them. No issues occur with linked form "B" but anytime someone edits a response, it creates a new record in spreadsheet "C". I have tried many things, but cannot come up with a solution.

Sample code:

```
function onFormSubmit(e){

var form = FormApp.openById('form_id'); // Load form 
var formResponses = form.getResponses();
var formResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length-1]; // last response
var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID); // Second Spreadsheet
var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
dataSheet.appendRow([x, y, z,]) // The form responses
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Your code is pushing responses ONLY to `spreadsheet C`. `Spreadsheet B` is connected directly to your Form and is being populated with standard google forms functionality (for clarity I'm going to use terms `SS Other` for what you labeled `C` and `SS Responses` for the spreadsheet you label as `B`).

An edited response will keep the same response ID, which can be utilized to match if an existing response has been received.  So in `SS Other`, you could create a response ID column, which you could check if an entry already exists.

To get the `id` of a response use:

```
var theID = formResponse.getId();
```

However, what I would do is just have `SS Other` just link to `SS Response` by using [getRange function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en). Much easier, and no scripting.

Also, your method for grabbing the latest response isn't the best practice (though it will probably be fine over 99% of the time). I'm guessing you do that for testing purposes. I use a setup like below to address this. Ultimately a "real" submission and a testing one (which grabs latest) both feed into `reviewResponse_` function with the response.

```
function entryMade(e) {
  //using e.response ties to exact submission that was triggered
  reviewResponse_(e.response);
}

function testEntryMade() {
  //use this for test entries/debugging.
  reviewResponse_(thisForm.getResponses()[thisForm.getResponses().length-1]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion/clarification pgSystemTester. I am going to use ImportRange.